# comparing doubles in linq iqueryable

Tags: c#, linq, double

In a linq query, what the acceptable way to compare a double to a

```
var object = context.myObject.Where(x.MyDouble == thisDouble);
```

I doubt the above would suffice?

Neil

Comment: Have you tested it? Did it work as expected? If not, what went wrong?

Comment: Yes it would work, within the bounds of comparing doubles for equality generally.

Comment: It would work if you fixed it to be a lambda `Where(x => x.MyDouble == thisDouble)`

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong syntax inside `.Where(...)`, it should be a lambda expression as below

```
var object = context.myObject.Where(x => x.MyDouble == thisDouble);
```